# Asymptotic Complexity of Logarithms and Powers

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, logarithm

So, clearly, `log(n)` is `O(n)`.  But, what about `(log(n))^2`?  What about `sqrt(n)` or `log(n)`—what bounds what?

There's a family of comparisons like this:

```
nᵃ   (vs.)   (log(n))ᵇ
```

I run into these comparisons a lot, and I've never come up with a good way to solve them.  Hints for tactics for solving the *general* case?

---

[EDIT: I'm not talking about the computational complexity of calculating the values of these functions.  I'm talking about the functions themselves.  E.g., `f(n) = n` is an upper bound on `g(n) = log(n)` because `f(n) ≤ c g(n)` for `c = 1` and `n₀ > 0`.]

Comment: _clearly, log(n) is O(n)_ -- where exactly did you hear this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

log(n)^a is always O(n^b), for any positive constants a, b.

Are you looking for a proof?  All such problems can be reduced to seeing that log(n) is O(n), by the following trick:

log(n)^a = O(n^b) is equivalent to:
log(n) = O(n^{b/a}), since raising to the 1/a power is an increasing function.
This is equivalent to 
log(m^{a/b}) = O(m), by setting m = n^{b/a}.
This is equivalent to log(m) = O(m), since log(m^{a/b}) = (a/b)*log(m).

You can prove that log(n) = O(n) by induction, focusing on the case where n is a power of 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
log n -- O(log n)
sqrt n -- O(sqrt n)
n^2 -- O(n^2)
(log n)^2 -- O((log n)^2)
```

`n^a` versus `(log(n))^b`

You need either bases or powers the same. So use your math to change `n^a` to `log(n)^(whatever it gets to get this base)` or `(whatever it gets to get this power)^b`. There is no general case

Answer (score 2):

> I run into these comparisons a lot (...)
>   Hints for tactics for solving the general case?

As you as about **general case** and that you following a lot into such questions. Here is what I recommend :

Use [limit definition of BigO notation](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/which-definition-of-asymptotic-growth-rate-should-we-teach), once you know:

```
f(n) = O(g(n)) iff limit (n approaches +inf) f(n)/g(n) exists and is not +inf
```

You can use [Computer Algebra System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system), for example opensource [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), here is in [Maxima documentation about limits](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_17.html) .

[For more detailed info and example - check out THIS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287667/asymptotic-comparison-of-functions/8790997#8790997)