# Asymptotic complexities of log versus powers

Tags: big-o, logarithm, asymptotic-complexity

Hey guys I'm working out some big-o problems from the Algorithms book by Dasgupta and am stuck on a few.

1) f(n) = n^0.1  g(n) = (log n)^10

According to the top answer on [Asymptotic Complexity of Logarithms and Powers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882915/asymptotic-complexity-of-logarithms-and-powers) ,
"log(n)^a is always O(n^b), for any positive constants a, b."
So for 1), f = omega(g)

2)
f(n) = n^1.01   g(n) = n log^2 n
My guess is f = omega(g). Is this example correct or a different case because log is squared and multiplied by n?

Please provide any explanation about the steps you take to solve these kind of problems

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to the first question is correct, as is your application of that rule.
Here's a proof that log(n) = O(n^a) for any a > 0 (which is clearly equivalent to said rule):

```
The derivative of n^a is a*(n^(a-1))
The derivative of log(n) = 1/n
Therefore, for large enough n, the derivative of n^a is more than the derivative of log(n)
Therefore, for large enough n, n^a > log(n)
Therefore log(n) = O(n^a)
```

Your answer to the second question is correct. Here's a proof:

```
g(n) = O(f(n)) if and only if log(log(n)) = O(n^0.01)
log(log(n)) = O(log(n)) so log(log(n)) = O(O(n^0.01)) = O(n^0.01)
```

Comment: Why is a*(n^(a-1)) < (1/n) for a>0 and large enough n?

Comment: Multiply both sides by n. a > 0, so the left hand side of the equation is a*(n^c) for some positive constant c. For large enough n, n^c > 1/a

Comment: Just now, you've showed that n^c > 1/a but shouldn't you be showing the opposite?

Comment: Woops, I've got a bit muddled in my answer, I've edited it to correct it